# How to open PDF file in new window in browser?

Tags: java, jsp, google-chrome, pdf, download

I'm trying to open a PDF file by requesting it from Rest endpoint. But in this case, the file is getting downloaded. I tried opening it in another window. There also it just shows new window and downloads it there.

I used Chrome. So in Chrome by default it downloads the file while in Firefox it shows the dialog box whether to open it or save it. I don't want that dialog box. But want to display the file in new window with all the features like download, print, etc which a normal pdf viewer will show.

Is there some way through which I can avoid downloading of the file by default and just display that file in another window? Content-Disposition is `attachment; filename="abc.pdf"` when I see the properties of the URL. Also, its content-type is `application/pdf;charset=utf-8`.

```
<a target="_blank" data-content-type="application/pdf" onclick="open(this.href, this.target, 'fullscreen=yes'); return false;" data-type="downloadTenPointDocument" href="<c:out value="${resultItem.offer.programInfoUrl}"/>">View 10-point</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed the properties of pdf file from attachment to inline and set it in response:

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName + ".pdf");
```

I am requesting the pdf file from server and then reading it and setting it in response, changing the properties of it in response, so that its default behavior of getting downloaded is overwritten.

Thank you everyone. The answer to change the property of pdf file was right.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do it directly from REST endpoint.
Use **target="_blank"** in anchor element on your page.

```
<a href="url_to_your_endpoint_generating_file.pdf" target="_blank">go</a>
```

Comment: I m doing the same thing it. I m using target="_blank". But in this case it opens up, a new window or tab and downloads over there, leaving the page blank. Whereas, I want the pdf to be displayed in that window.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to erase attachment; property from content disposition header.

Comment: Can you please suggest me a way of doing it?

Comment: As you wrote your header looks like content-disposition : "attachment; filename="abc.pdf""

Comment: Can you please add code snippet of from which you are requesting the pdf?

Comment: I can't share that link with you. Since it being authorized. But I will add how I m doing it.

Comment: If I understand correctly you are requesting pdf file from rest endpoint which needs authorization and its not yours endpoint. Basically what you need to do is to remove attachment; property. You cant do that directly from a link. You could request it from javascript and make a blob from that url and then return it in another window. This would work but then you will need to add authorization info to frontend which i think is not the best idea. I think the best solution would be to write a rest client request the pdf and response it to front from your controller with different headers.

Answer (score 0):

i did like that and it worked: (it wont start to download, and it will open in a new tab (target _blank) if same tab, thenit is (target _self)

`<a href="<c:url value='resources/pdfs/your pdf(already in the project).pdf' />" target="_blank"> show pdf in a new tab</a>`